# Retrieving Mails/Attachements from Exchange Server

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to connect with a mailbox on our exchange server, and I have the servername, username and password.

At the moment I have the following code to connect to my personal mailbox and this is working fine:-

```
            app = new Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            Helpers.AddToErrorLog("CESTOAD mailbox", DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Logging into CESTOAD mailbox");
            ns.Logon(user, password, false, false);


            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["ComDocsAttachements"];
```

However, I cannot find out how to connect to another account with a username and password on the same exchange server. When I change the user and password in the Logon, it still retreives my account.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what library, or API you are using to connect to Exchange, but I would guess that the logon call is still detecting your initial logon, and regarding you as authenticated, and not trying to log you on with the new credentials. Is there a Logoff method you could call first?

Comment: ns.Logoff();
                ns.Logon(user, password, false, false);
but was not helpful, still logging into the same account